Can't resolve 'dom-helpers/addClass' and 'dom-helpers/removeClass' in @mui/material/react-transition-group
This issue just started with @mui/material 5.15.18. I have tried everything to resolve it by installing another version of react-transition-group but the problem is with the version of react-transition-group @mui/material is using internally. How can I change the version of the internal react-transition-group @mui/material is using?
Is there  a better option I should consider because I don't like the idea of changing the internal library of a library.
